# Typescript class method called by external function vs internal function

Tags: typescript

I have have a class like this:

```
export class HelloComponent {

  recipient = 'World';

  constructor() {
    this.sayHello();
  }

  sayHello() {
    const msg = `Hello ${this.recipient}`;
    console.log(msg);
  }
}
```

When called from the constructor, `sayHello` works fine.

However when the method gets called by `window.requestAnimationFrame` it throws:

```
// Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'recipient' of null
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Where is `sayHello` actually executed? Presumably this is a scoping issue.

Comment: It's called from another class method

Comment: As far as I know, Angular classes are Typescript classes. If you pass the Angular component method `sayHello` as a callback, it will throw the same error because `this` has been lost.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery and ConnersFan - I thought I was illustrating the issue but it turns out I omitted part of the problem that was causing the issue. My apologies. I updated the question and added an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you currently have something like this:

```
const hc = new HelloComponent();
window.requestAnimationFrame(hc.sayHello);
```

change the second line to:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(hc.sayHello.bind(hc));
```

or to:

```
window.requestAnimationFrame(() => hc.sayHello());
```

Both syntaxes will ensure that the callback still has `this` bound to `hc`. Regarding the `bind`-based solution, see also the explanation in [this MDN article ("Creating a bound function")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Creating_a_bound_function).

Answer (score 0):

When class methods are called outside the class, the `this` reference no longer refers to the class. The method needs to be changed to a property:

```
sayHello = () => {
  const msg = `Hello ${this.recipient}`;
  console.log(msg);
}
```